# How do I remove wax or Mop-and-Glow from Pergo floors?

Tags: floor

How do I remove wax or Mop-and-Glow  from Pergo floors?

Comment: Do you specifically have Pergo brand floors or a laminate floor?

Comment: If you know what was used, check the label. The  "waxes" I've used say they can be removed with household amonia. No idea what that would do The floor. Then again, no idea why anoyone would do anything more to a wood floor than keep it clean, at least not until it was time for serious refinishing decades after installation.

Answer (score 2):

I won't suggest a brand in particular, but there are commercially available cleaners meant specifically for stripping hardwood/pergo/laminated flooring. A quick Amazon/Google search for 'Floor Polish Remover' brings up many options. It appears that this could be quite the project.

It appears as though some people also use a large rotary floor buffer/polisher to even out/remove any waxy buildup. This could also be a 'Pro Project' or something you could contract out.

Good luck.

(P.S. Whatever the outcome, I'd be interested. I also have hardwood floors that may need to be stripped)

Answer (score 0):

Moved into a house with 50's linoleum; LOTS of wax buildup.
Tryed one of those fancy 'Floor Polish Removers' at $20 a bottle. It had triethylamine or triethanolamine or some such in it; looked and smelled like 70's vintage floor cleaning chemistry. Bottom line, it didn't work very well on serious wax buildup.

Then tried a bottle of [Formula 409](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_409), developed 1957, on the floor. It worked wonders. Took off all the old wax with just a good scrubbing. With a fresh coat of wax, my kitchen again shines like the early space age.

[Cleaning floors with Formula 409](https://www.formula409.com/how-do-i-clean/floors-2/)